# Iterating through a DateTime in MMM yyyy format

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a couple of `DateTime` `startTime` and `endTime`. I would like them to be in MMM yyyy format ("August 2017") but if I parse them `ToString`, i can't loop because, well, it's a string now, there is no `AddMonths` method. For exemple :

```
 var formattedStartTime = startTime.ToString("MMMM yyyy");
 var formattedEndTime = endTime.ToString("MMMM yyyy");
 for (var date = formattedStartTime; date < formattedEndTime; date = date.AddMonths(1)) // nope
```

How can i parse my variables and loop through every month in between two dates ?

Comment: Why don't you just loop on `startTime` and `endTime` and format to string only when you need that?

Answer (score 3):

By calling `ToString` you are *obviously* converting your dates to a string, which know nothing about the original date they represent and as such also cannot perform any date related operations.

The solution is to simply convert to string **only** when you are actually displaying the object:

```
for (var date = startTime; date < endTime; date = date.AddMonths(1))
{
    Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("MMM yyyy"));
}
```

Be careful with such date comparisons though, since depending on the actual days of the month and the time component in the `startTime` and `endTime`, you might skip or include a result you do not expect.

For example with `startTime = new DateTime(2017, 1, 2)` and `endTime = new DateTime(2017, 2, 3)` (February 3rd), you would get February in the result but with `endTime = new DateTime(2017, 2, 1)` (February 1st) you wouldn’t.